# How to mock the import of a module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Consider the following project structure:

```
/project
- folder/
    - some_config_module.py
    - func.py
- test/
    - __init__.py
    - test_config.py
    - test.py
```

Assume the following code

```
# func.py
import folder.some_config_module as config

def search_for_data():
    var = config.predefined_parameter
    # rest of code
```

I would now like to write a unit-test for `search_for_data`. To do this in a sensible way, I need to mock the import of the `some_config_module`, i.e. my try

```
# test.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import tests.test_config as test_config
from folder.func import serach_for_data


class TestSearchForData(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('folder.some_config_module')
    def test_one(self, test_config):
        self.assertEqual(search_for_data(), 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This does not result in the expected behaviour: what I would like is for `search_for_data` inside of `test_one` to import `test.test_config` and not `folder.some_config_module`. This code was based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257709/python-mock-imported-module-method) answer... But I seem to misunderstand something rather fundamental about `mock`..

Comment: I think you have to specifie in the `@patch` the name of the test function, not the real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function `search_for_data` is using the name `config` imported in `func`'s global namespace, you need to override that instead of the overriding `folder.some_config_module`.

```
@patch('folder.func.config')
```

An import like `import folder.some_config_module as config` is equivalent to doing:

```
import folder.some_config_module
config = folder.some_config_module
del folder.some_config_module
```

Hence it adds the variable `config` to that module(`func.py`)'s namespace and that's what then `search_for_data` is using. From `search_for_data`'s perspective, it doesn't matter if `config` is a name that refers to a module or it refers to something else, it just knows that it needs to load that name from the global namespace(in this case it's the module `func.py`)

---

At runtime `search_for_data` will look for `config` in its global namespace(`search_for_data.__globals__`), mock patches this globals dictionary and replaces the name `config` in this dictionary temporarily with the mock object and during teardown it restores it back.

```
import os.path as path
from unittest.mock import patch

def func():
    print(path)


print(f"Before patch: {func.__globals__['path']}")
with patch("__main__.path"):
    print(f"During patch: {func.__globals__['path']}")
    func()

print(f"After patch: {func.__globals__['path']}")
```

Outputs:

```sh
Before patch: <module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py'>
During patch: <MagicMock name='path' id='140233829017776'>
<MagicMock name='path' id='140233829017776'>
After patch: <module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py'>
```

Comment: @peak_finding_prob You don't need to patch the globals dict manually, `patch` will do that for you. You just need to override the variable `config` in the `func` module where `search_for_data` is actually present. I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: @peak_finding_prob `__main__.path`: When we run a file directly with Python, say you have a file named `foo.py` with the above code, it runs under the module `__main__`, hence the pattern `__name__ = '__main__'` is also seen in Python files.